# MySQL:Deleting two columns from table using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to update two columns without deleting the entire row. Here is what I am using:

```
$sql='update users set token='',timestamp='' where token=?';
   $stmt=$db_con->stmt_init();
   $stmt->prepare($sql_3);
   $stmt->bind_param('s',$token);
   $stmt->execute();
```

However, it gives me this error: T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING. Now the query works fine when I use it through the MySQL CLI as `update users set token='',timestamp='' where token='blahblah';` How can I get around this?

Comment: Yessir. I started last month. Loving it so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$sql="update users set token='',timestamp='' where token=?";
```

You can find more info here how to escape a string.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

you should be using.

```
$sql="update users set token='',timestamp='' where token=?";
```

notice the double quote (") on start and end of the string.

since you are using multiple single quotes in your string PHP does not understand this, and will throw an error. you need to tell php to escape the quote. you can do it in two ways.

1) By using PHP's `\` escape character infront of the quote.

```
'update users set token=\'\',timestamp=\'\' where token=?';
```

2) use double quote for the string instead of single quote.

```
"update users set token=\'\',timestamp=\'\' where token=?";
```

both should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here i would like to inform you that as query was in single quotes and you have used single quotes more than one time in the query string. PHP will accept string from first quote to next quote, thats why you getting error but in command line this do not generate error

```
$sql='update users set token='',timestamp='' where token=?'; to
$sql="update users set token='',timestamp='' where token=?";
```